# Systemd create service who is able to display itself in a full screen terminal

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi, command-line-interface, systemd, xfce

i've made a CLI app with node js.
How can i create a service who display it in a full screen terminal in case it crashes and need to be restarted?
I'm using lxterminal in a raspberry pi.
(Yes, i need the desktop environement for other reasons)
Thanks.

Comment: One of the key features of a service is that it **doesn't** run in a terminal. Standard out is rerouted to the `journalctl` logs. It seems all you need is a 3 line wrapper shell script. Just start your program, and if it exits, restart it.

Comment: I think i see what you mean. Can you suggest me some example about it?